# Calling a function inside for loop but how to skip an index inside that function

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am trying to code the switch on empty (SOE) algorithm proposed by Yufei Tao in his paper, "Finding Maximum degrees in hidden bipartite graphs". I created a function that checks the matching of each element of a list and appends 1 when it matches and appends 0 when it does not. Furthermore, when it appends 0 it switches, as in breaks from the loop.

Now, this function performs only one iteration. I use a `for` loop to have it perform multiple iterations. But after performing one iteration I need the loop to check in the function the indexes it has already checked and directly go to the indexes that have not been matched yet.

To save the indexes already explored I used the concept of memoization and saved them in another list. I did this inside the function. Now I want to perform the loop on the function but need to use the saved indexes list and have the function skip the indexes already explored.
List C can be taken as some candidates that have qualifications and set B as a job description that shows the requirements. So if a candidate in C has the qualification in B, it forms an edge as 1, and if not then it does not form an edge as 0.
This is the example code I have made so far:

```
C = ["s", "s", "c", "d"]
B = ["s", "b", "e", "d"]

def code(B,C):
  idx = []
  D = []
  Mat = {}
  for i in B:
    D = []
    idx = []
    for key,j in enumerate(C):
      if i == j:
        D.append(1)
        idx.append(key)
      else:
        D.append(0)
        idx.append(key)
        break

    Mat[i] = [D, idx]
  return Mat

F = {}
for i in range(0,len(C)):
  try:
      F[i] = code(B,C)
  except:
      for value in F[i].items():
        if value[1] in value:
          continue
print(F)
```

The output of F is:

```
{0: {'s': [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]], 'b': [[0], [0]], 'e': [[0], [0]], 'd': [[0], [0]]}, 1: {'s': [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]], 'b': [[0], [0]], 'e': [[0], [0]], 'd': [[0], [0]]}, 2: {'s': [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]], 'b': [[0], [0]], 'e': [[0], [0]], 'd': [[0], [0]]}, 3: {'s': [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]], 'b': [[0], [0]], 'e': [[0], [0]], 'd': [[0], [0]]}}
```

What I need the code to do is in the next iteration, it should start with the next indices, for example, it should be

```
    {1: {'s': [1,1,0,0],[0,1,2,3]], 'b': [[0,0],[0,1]], 'e': [[0,0], [0,1]], 'd': [[0,0], [0,1]]}
```

and so on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and try to ask a *specific question*. Also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to show your code exactly as you actually have it. To understand the question, it would be helpful to explain: for the given `B` and `C` values, what happens when you run the code? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different?

Comment: (con't.) What is the specific problem that the code is supposed to solve? You said something about "hidden bipartite graphs", but I don't understand how the `B` and `C` data is supposed to represent any kind of graph, nor do I understand what `D` should look like or what it represents. It would be helpful to use function and variable names that indicate the purpose and intent of those functions and variables.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the edit. I am trying to mimic a bipartite graph using two lists B and C. D is a matrix that shows the connected and disconnected edges. I'm trying to show it using 0 as disconnected edges and 1s as connected edges. D would be a matrix containing the edges of the elements in the lists B and C. Currently, my function only gives the same input again when I use a for-loop. It should move onto the next indices and the last row of the matrix D should print all the 0s and 1s for all the elements. I hope this clears what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "I am trying to mimic a bipartite graph using two lists B and C" Okay, and how do those lists represent nodes, edges etc.? Where I see `C = ["s", "s", "c", "d"]`, what picture of a graph should I be imagining? For the given input, can you solve the problem by hand? It would be helpful to show the exact, complete desired structure of `D` after all the code runs. (It is also not very helpful for comprehension, that `code` also has its own local `D`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function default argument to store values, try this:

```
def f(x,y=[]):
    y.append(x)
    return y
```

f() will remember all arguments it was called with.